# After converting Sklearn decision tree using Onnx, is there a way to get the index of the leaf that each sample is predicted as?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, onnx

I used Onnx to convert a Sklearn decision tree:

```
# Convert into ONNX format
from skl2onnx import convert_sklearn
from skl2onnx.common.data_types import FloatTensorType
initial_type = [('float_input', FloatTensorType([None, X_train.shape[1]]))]
onx = convert_sklearn(clf, initial_types=initial_type, options={type(clf): {'nocl': True}})
with open(file_loc, "wb") as f:
    f.write(onx.SerializeToString())
```

I didn't find how to get the predicted nodes.
I tried this:

```
# Compute the prediction with ONNX Runtime
import onnxruntime as rt
import numpy
sess = rt.InferenceSession(file_loc)
input_name = sess.get_inputs()[0].name
label_name = sess.get_outputs()[1].name
pred_onx = sess.run([label_name], {input_name: X_test.values.astype(np.float32)})[0]
```

But the best I managed to get was the probabilities.

Thanks,
Ilan.